# Calendar Month y MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

mi duda es la siguiente, 
Como puedo insertar un dato date time a mi base de datos mysql desde windows form usando un month calendar

Comment: Hola Nogthings, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Sería bueno que colocaras algo de código, un ejemplo [mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Así mismo, te invito a revisar la sección de [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a a SOes, aquí se reciben mejor las preguntas con detalles, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar un dato dateTime a tu base de datos mysql debes realizar lo siguiente:

```
//recoges el día seleccionado del monthCalendar en una variable DateTime
DateTime fecha =  monthCalendar1.SelectionStart; 

//tu conexión
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conexion);

//tu query de insercción con el parámetro fecha en la tabla que corresponda
string query = @"INSERT INTO tutabla (fecha) values (@fecha)";

//abres tu conexión
cn.Open(); 

//instancias un MySqlCommand y le indicas la query en tu conexion
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn); 

//Le indicas tu el nombre de tu parámetro y el tipo
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", MySqlDbType.DateTime); 

//le indicas que el parámetro fecha tendra el valor de tu variable DateTime Fecha
cmd.Parameters["@fecha"].Value = fecha; 

//ejecutas la query 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//cierras tu conexión
cn.Close();
```